# Damaged Sd card

Tags: partitioning, sd-card, format, testdisk, drive-letter

My sd card was damaged and it asked me to format. A year ago the same thing happened and I format the card and recover the data by recovering software.
But now I did wrong by removing the drive letter and used TestDisk.
test disk did not find any partition. In simple words, this new method did not work for me.

So like before I format the card and try to recover the data by recovering software but nothing is recovered even a single file. There was very important data.  I tried many recovering Software but nothing is showing up.

Comment: When SD cards have faults you dispose of them. You don't keep using them.

Comment: I’m voting to close this because there is no question.  The post contains only statements.

Answer (score 4):

You were lucky last year. That incident should have taught you that SD cards are not reliable and you should not trust your important data to a single SD card.

This time you were out of luck. Your data is gone.

Storage media fail every now and then. SD cards are quite fragile, but HDDs and SSDs sometimes just die too. If your data is of any importance, you absolutely **must have backups**. Everything you don't have a copy of is lost in case of failure of a single device, single software bug, single malware attack or a single human mistake.

Comment: At this point your best bet is to use professional file recovery service. It won't be cheap and success is not guaranteed.

Comment: Better to take care next time and don't ever use sd card in mobile

Comment: That's not the problem - lack of backups is your problem. What if you lose the mobile or it gets stolen? What if malware erases your files? What if you accidentally spill water on the phone and it gets damaged? The only reliable way to not lose your files is to have copies elsewhere.